# Using diffstat with subversion?

Tags: svn, command-line, diffstat

Could anyone give me examples, how I could use diffstat with subversion?

I mean, using [**diffstat**](http://freshmeat.net/projects/diffstat/) to analyze and produce statistics about one or multiple commits.

*NOTE: Linux commandline examples are OK ;)*

Comment: And please, someone who is allowed to add new tags, add a tag "diffstat" to this question ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply pipe any diff to diffstat. For example, if you want a stat of the changes made in a specific revision, just retrieve that change from svn and pipe it to diffstat.

```
$ svn diff -r1234:1235 | diffstat
```

You can obviously pipe anything in that svn can create diffs of, which includes diffs between branches, tags and folders and also ranges of revisions.

```
$ svn diff svn://server/trunk svn://server/tags/tag1 | diffstat
$ svn diff -r 1000:2000 svn://server/trunk/file1 | diffstat
```